# Take data from URL in MySql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to take data from DB via simple script

```
<a href='category.php?CAT=Shoes'>Shoes</a>
```

then simple show all rows with the specific data in "CAT" column like this:

```
$CAT = $_GET['CAT'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Shop WHERE CAT = $CAT" ;
       $result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
echo"
... results
"}}
```

The problem is that this script does work with INT (for example SELECT CAT = 5 like category.php?CAT=5) but not with VARCHAR (SELECT CAT = Shoes like category.php?CAT=Shoes). Now I'm not sure why is this happening.
With Error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM Shop WHERE CAT = '$CAT'" ;

Comment: and also check you column type in db

Comment: Because `CAT` field is `INT`?

Comment: Vikram, so simple, you are absolute genius ! Thank you, bro

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Shop WHERE CAT = '$CAT'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pass `$cat` as string

```
$cat = $_GET['CAT'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Shop WHERE CAT = '{$cat}'" ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($row, true) . '</pre><br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend doing the character escape to prevent an SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php